# jQuery Smooth Photo Fading

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have this code:

HTML

```
<div>
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-2-blue-series/64/a-92-128.png" data-src-alt="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sitemap-kit/64/sitemap_kit-52-128.png" alt="3" />
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/design-creativity-round/128/11-128.png" data-src-alt="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-set-1/64/flat_set_1-03-128.png" alt="2" />
<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/camera-and-photography-3/64/Person_Image-128.png" data-src-alt="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/modern-universal/32/icon-09-128.png" alt="3" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var overHover = function () { //zibi - efekt overhover
    var newSourceImg = $(this).data('src-alt');
    $(this).data('src-alt', $(this).attr('src'));
    $(this).attr('src', newSourceImg);
}

$(function() {
    $('img[data-src-alt]').each(function() {
        new Image().src = $(this).data('src-alt');
    }).hover(overHover, overHover);
});
```

How to make smooth photo fade in on hover? Of course, I mean the fadeIn() and fadeOut() methods.
Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xampoo/6d495zkt/2/

Comment: You can't smoothly animate changing an images `src`, since you need both images loaded simultaneously to be able to show the mid-fade states. Off the top of my head, I would suggest you try having two images in a container and transition the opacity of each image.

Comment: As above, alternatively, fadeOut, change the src, then fadeIn - won't "transition" but would be "smooth" - depending on your definition of smooth.  eg `img.fadeOut(() => { mg[0].src = ..; img.fadeIn() });`  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g8xnv3q4/ tweak the timeout (150) until it feels right.

Comment: You're right: in fact, both pictures must be loaded at the same time, otherwise the transition effect is not satisfactory. Perhaps the best way is to just use CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/hy09ox8z/ Thanks for your help!